# MVVM vs SQLiteOpenHelper for android database. Having a bit of a confusion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, mvvm, android-sqlite

I have been looking into how databases work in android and have been learning MVVM (Model–View–ViewModel). But I am seeing a lot of examples of SQliteOpenHelper being used here rather then MVVM.

After learning MVVM, I am starting to get confused about SQLiteOpenHelper(Though I have not learned anything about it). I do understand that MVVM is the standard and that MVVM has SQLite in it, but when I look at examples of SQLite in stack overflow, I am seeing cursors and stuff, which I do not know.

**For the application that I am planning to make is using MVVM or SQLiteOpenHelper better?**
The data that I need to store in column is date, Something, something, something. So just four columns of data. I will be storing data locally.

**I do like MVVM though, but does it go well for my purpose?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*MVVM* is a software architectural pattern and not a particular implementation. The database itself should reside within the *Model* portion of your code. Here `SQLiteOpenHelper` comes into play. It's the standard to access databases in *Android*. Therefore any actual implementation you choose relies on it as well.

To get started with databases you should consider using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as it's an abstraction of the database, providing DAOs and Entities. No need to implement an `SQLiteOpenHelper` or handle cursors.

Comment: Hey, would you recommend MVVM or SQLiteOpenHelper for my application?

Comment: Since you're using the Jetpack utilities, you should use `Room` with your _MVVM_. When you feel confortable with that, you should have a look into `SQLiteOpenHelper`. But more importantly you need understand what _MVVM_ is. Eventually you could implement the _MVVM_ pattern with an `SQLiteOpenHelper` or without any tool you're using right now.